Lidar sensor doesnt function properly
So I am new to Gazebo and ROS2, and I am trying to implement a Lidar sensor. I am following the official documentation of Gazebo Fortress, and the tutorial inside it. I copied the code from that, to see how it works, and it runs, but the data doesn't show up in RVIZ2 (it publishes and rviz subscribes to the topic, but it visualizes 0 points from 0 messages). I've linked a short version of my output, when I echo the topic, this goes on basically forever. The vehicle and the thing it senses isn't moving
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 117
    nanosec: 0
  frame_id: tank/chassis/gpu_lidar
height: 1
width: 640
fields:
- name: x
  offset: 0
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- name: y
  offset: 4
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- name: z
  offset: 8
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- name: intensity
  offset: 16
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- name: ring
  offset: 24
  datatype: 4
  count: 1
is_bigendian: false
point_step: 32
row_step: 20480
data:
- 0
- 0
- 128
- 127
- 0
- 0
- 128
- 255
- 0
- 0
- 192
- 255
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 128
- 127
- 0
- 0
- 128
- 255
- 0
- 0
- 192
- 255
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 128
- 127
- 0
- 0
- 128
- 255
- 0
- 0
- 192
- 255
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 128
- 127
- 0
- 0
- 128
- 255
- 0
- 0
- 192
- 255
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- '...'
is_dense: false
---


I think you can first confirm whether your lidar-plugins are consistent with gazebo, and then check whether the syntax of your sdf file is correct. I also encountered the same problem as you before, because I misused the macro definition and plugins could not be loaded correctly
